# On the starting angle of the double slider circle

Tags: ios

[To realize the starting angle, and the end angle of the double slider circle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gou5v.png)

Comment: You need to add an actual question, and preferably some source code. A image and a vague sentence is not enough to be able to help.

Comment: https://github.com/lotus-lotus/sc  Here's my code

Comment: The code needs to be in the question not on Github. You need to make the effort to summarise your problem well. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: There are some problems in the starting angle and the end angle in the code